# VScode debug mode can't find my config.json file

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, config, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug a go application on VScode, but my config.json can't be found. I am getting a `Error occurred while reading config. panic: open config.json: The system cannot find the file specified` error.

This is my launch.json file and I have my workspace path set to the src, which is where I have my go files and main package.

````
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\src"
        }
    ]
}```

The config.go file is a level higher than the src folder. I have attached a screenshot of my workspace structure. What am I doing wrong?



 [![screenshot of my workspace structure][1]][1] 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz4KL.png
````

Comment: IMHO better generate unit tests and debug test cases (you will see the button above) so you don't need this "configurations", anyway there are tons of guides for newbies like this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/debugging-go-code-with-visual-studio-code

Comment: From https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#configuration: "The `program` folder is used as the working directory if `cwd` is omitted or empty. Can you try to configure `cwd` to be "." or "${workspaceFolder}" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this config

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}"
        }
    ]
```